# how i can take variable from function for another function SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

**I wont print in console currentCity, for the use city name in another function! Please Help me.**

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var currentCity: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    print(currentCity) //----error not printing CITY NAME
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)

        } else {

            if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {

                if let city = placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] as? NSString {

                    self.cityLbl.text = city as String
                    self.currentCity = city as String

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Put the print line in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method at the end of the `else` scope.

Comment: i need use city name in another function! your variant is worked but i dont need print in the didUpdateLocations. i wont take this city name and use this name in the json

Comment: Think asynchronous and call the *other function* from the delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print city in `didUpdateLocations`.

```
                if let city = placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] 
                                      as? NSString {

                    self.cityLbl.text = city as String
                    self.currentCity = city as String
                    print(currentCity) // here you get string
                       // call that function here
                    self.myfunction(cityName: currentCity)

                }
```

**Function**

```
func myfunction(cityName : String) -> Void {
        // your string with city name
    }
```

Comment: i need  use city name in another function! your variant is worked but i dont need print in the didUpdateLocations. i wont take this city name and use this name in the json

Comment: then call function below the cityname where you got that string.

Comment: very big thanks my friend! i am try this variant and say you work or no.
sorry my english very bad) i am from Caucasus)

Answer (score 2):

Location manager is an asynchronous function. Which means your code will initiate the function but carry on with the next piece of code, and not wait to get the location, which will eventually finish later.

So even though you are calling your update location before the print function, by the time the code is executing the print it has not gotten the location yet and your current city is nil.

Print the name from the location manager function or add a completion closure. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

func viewDidLoad() is called first and at the time the location is not fetched. Try printing after func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) is called.

Comment: i am trying make new func example: func printVar(){

print(currentCity)

}

after didUpdateLocations , and call this func in the ViewDidLoad, but again nil!